# GIf image convert into Base64 in android, without using Compress

Tags: android

- My code is, in this code all image are convert into base 64, but in gif image also in png, i want as a gif, after convert.

  ```
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
  byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
  return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

=>This code is working successfully

```
 byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);

 Base64.encodeToString(inputData, Base64.NO_WRAP)

 public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}

public static String encodeToString(byte[] input, int flags) {
    try {
        return new String(encode(input, flags), "US-ASCII");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // US-ASCII is guaranteed to be available.
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```